# Creating files in specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, timer, cmd

I have a little problem - I am trying to create a `bat` file in a specific folder with another batch file

```
echo How many hours must go from startup to shutdown?
set input=
set /p input= Timer: 
SET /A Sekunder = %input% * 3600
SET startupfolder=%SystemDrive%\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\AutoShutdown.bat
echo %startupfolder%
echo c:\windows\system32\shutdown -s -f -t %Sekunder% > %startupfolder%
pause
```

Am I doing anything wrong...?

Comment: What are the symptoms of the problem?  This looks like the correct way to set a variable, but it will not do anything to create a file.

Comment: Use the [edit] button to add that code to the question.

Comment: Well this is my code:
http://pastebin.com/6hST2LMV
:) I know that code up there doesnt create a file, but I am new to stackoverflow and it didnt want to let me paste more than a little peace of code o,o

I am trying to create a file in the startup/start folder of windows :3

Comment: You need to include the entirety of the relevant code in your SO post, not only in offsite links.

Comment: Well this "stackoverflow" is hard lol.
http://hastebin.com/anugatehax.dos better? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... The problem was that it needed "" 's in front, and behind the folder name as it contained spaces :)

My program is now fully working :p Ty anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Read at [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) page:

> Note, any long filenames must be surrounded in "double quotes".

```
echo Hvor mange timer skal der gaa fra startup til shutdown?
set input=
set /p input= Timer: 
SET /A Sekunder = %input% * 3600
SET startupfolder=%SystemDrive%\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\AutoShutdown.bat
echo %startupfolder%
echo c:\windows\system32\shutdown -s -f -t %Sekunder% > "%startupfolder%"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%userprofile%`

If you echo out your path, as you do but didn't read, you'll see you have `c:\\etc`.